# Convert unicode string (from clipboard) to CP1252 (or other CP) text

Tags: vb.net, unicode, codepages

I'm trying to outgrow AutoIt for simple programs and write in Visual Basic instead. I have an AutoIt script that converts the Unicode text in the Windows clipboard to text (by default in codepage 1252, but optionally in another codepage), using WideCharToMultiByte. What I can't figure out is how to do the same thing in Visual Basic.

I know how to get the clipboard into a variable:

```
Dim clpData As String
clpData = (My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText())
```

What I can't figure out is how to convert that string to non-Unicode (for example codepage 1252) text, and hours of searching didn't come up with an answer, though maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Look at the example in the Encoding.Convert Method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I found it earlier among the dozens of things I searched through, but I was too much of a beginner to make it work. I'm still a beginner, but, because you suggested it, this time I figured it all out, and got it working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You may be a beginner, but you have the motivation to try, may be fail a time or two, but you succeed in the end.  That effort is what I like to see. :)